# Altitudes of a triangle are concurrent

Tags: geometry

I saw this problem in an Ukrainian Math Olympiad:
Prove the three altitudes of a triangle are concurrent using the following diagram with elementary geometry. (That is, prove that the line that passes by A1 and E1 forms a right angle with the segment below.) I attempted to show that the angle of vertex B1 was the complementary of the one in Z (the small one). The image looked something like this:

[image]

Comment: Did the image look something *like* that, or was it that?  I wouldn't even know what the picture meant, frankly … the most obvious interpretations of it seem to require that $A_1$ is a vertex of an isosceles triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\triangle ZB_1A_1$ be a triangle, and let its heights $B_1C_1$ and $ZD_1$ intersect at $E_1$. We will try to prove that $A_1E_1\perp ZB_1$.

On the picture above, the bigger circle is drawn on $ZB_1$ as a diameter, and it goes through $C_1$, $D_1$ due to the right angles at $C_1$, $D_1$. Similarly, the smaller circle is drawn on $A_1E_1$ as a diameter, and it also goes through $C_1$, $D_1$.

Now, $\angle{ZA_1E_1}=\angle{C_1A_1E_1}=\angle{C_1D_1E_1}$(peripheral angles in the smaller circle)$=\angle C_1D_1Z=\angle C_1B_1Z$ (peripheral angles in the bigger circle)$=90^\circ-\angle C_1ZB_1$

So the angles $\angle ZA_1E_1$ and $\angle C_1ZB_1$ add up to $90^\circ$ - and the statement $A_1E_1\perp B_1Z$ then follows directly.